# Can I estimate irradiance from photovoltaic panels' output data?

Tags: solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I'm trying to figure out a way to estimate irradiance from the data I get out of photovoltaics panels; irradiance, or any other variable that would be appropriate to my use case/context, which I hope will make things clearer:

Context: A photovoltaic farm, with panels mounted on 'trackers' (structures that move to optimize the light incidence angle). Those structures' positioning motors are fed by a smaller, dedicated panel mounted beside the other big ones.

When light is low, it is more efficient to leave the panels at a 0° angle, not only for production, but it allows the motors batteries to charge.

I've been asked to find a way to estimate when we're under that threshold from the data we gather from the battery and its panel. We have access to the panel's voltage and current, and to the battery's charge, temperature, output voltage and current.

Now, I'm a programmer, and this is way out of my comfort zone. I've tried searching on the internet, but what I found was either unhelpful or looked like the recipe for a satanic ritual to me.

Could someone help me get started?

Comment: Panel short-circuit current output is roughly proportional to irradience. Into a constant load, any movement that increases power output or current output is a movement that's worth making. If you have MPPTs, they can confound the 'constant load' assumption, but even so, if they have a power output monitor, or you can measure their current output into a constant voltage load, maximising that by moving the panels ought to be a Good Thing (TM) to do.

Comment: If there is no direct sunlight then giving the panels the best view of the sky will give the max output.

Comment: Your description raises a few questions.  Is every panel controlled from a central point, or does each panel make its own decisions where it should be pointing? If it is the latter, how do you take into account passing clouds? Will the array look like a Mexican Wave as a small cloud passes over? Surely you know the exact geographic location of your array and hence can calculate the altitude of the sun at any time on any day. Just park the whole array in the 0° position so many minutes before sunset and after sunrise, then start tracking.

Comment: Turn the trackers on for a minute every half hour or so. (Compute the cosine error that can creep in from the Earth's rotation during that half hour; it won't be much)

Answer (score 2):

Solar panels usually feed into an MPPT (maximum power point tracker) converter. That should tell you how many watts the panel is producing. Alternatively, if you have volts and amps, then watts = volts X amps.

Peak sunlight on a sunny day is approximately 1kW per square metre. Solar panels are approximately 20% efficient, but if you have access to the data sheet for the panel, look in that. They do vary, and modern ones may be better than 20%.

So if you know the area of panel, the efficiency and the power coming out of the panel, you can estimate the strength of the light.

But is there any reason why that matters? The most important thing is how much power (watts) you're getting, and whether or not that's enough to make it worthwhile keeping the system turned on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
Why that matters ? Because those trackers move pretty much all day long, and under low light conditions the battery powering the motor tends to run out.  By putting it in a 'rest' position when a to-be-determined threshold is reached, we allow for the battery to charge.  
Also, it is a bit more complicated than just moving a panel around, as those are double-sided, and using diffuse light might be more efficient in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video about diy solar panel tracker. For measuring the irradiance as others said measuring Jsc at short circuit is the best way to measure irradiance. Rather than using a small solar panel you can use a photodiode which is optimised for measuring at short circuit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6QIutZfsFs

Comment: This is not a DIY project, but several big farms of 5-10 MW each.  
I'm trying to use a small panel because it's already there, with data readily accessible.

Comment: I think for a big farm like that you can simply set the path of the motors based on the known trajectory of the sun rather than use the panels data to control it. I believe there will already be software or code for that somewhere. I could imagine heavy cloud cover causing some erratic behaviour of a farm based on a solar panel determining the direction of travel due to the light being very diffuse. If you definitely want to do it based on panel data I would put the cell into 5 V reverse bias and use the current data - at such a reverse bias the current will be v linear w.r.t. irradiance

Comment: We're already using the known trajectory of the sun. I'm not asking how to track the sun or find the best angle, I'm asking how to find out when it's not worth it anymore to do it, i.e when the light indeed is very diffuse.

Could you expand on the last part ?

Comment: Sure I can expand. If your cell is hooked up to a maximum power point tracker that doesnt adjust the applied voltage often, then a change in irradiance can cause the current to change for 2 reasons. 1. a decrease in the short circuit current, or 2. the cells open circuit voltage has changed (because this is also dependent on irradiance) and then rather than being at maximum power point your applie voltage is on the steep part of the JV curve. Therefore at a fixed max power voltage the relationship between measure current and irradiance is not linear.

Comment: If you then go to short circuit i.e. 0 V you dont have the problem of reason 2 (the voltage change) so the relationship between current and irradiance is now linear. Going to -5V is just really encouraging those charges to get out and isn't completely necessary it's just what I do when I am using photodiodes as it increases the sensitivity a bit. For your application that is probably negligible